# Prove that $C^1(- \infty, +\infty)$ is a subspace of $F(-\infty,+\infty)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I always have trouble on how to show these when they are not simple algebraic functions. I know that you have to use the subspace theorem where you must prove the axioms that they are closed under addition and multiplication but i am not sure how i would start this.

Answer (score 0):

You have simply to show that, given $f,g:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ of class $C^1$, and $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R} $, the linear combination $\lambda f + \mu g$ is of class $C^1$. But this is clear, since

$$\frac{d}{dx} (\lambda f + \mu g) = \lambda f' + \mu g'$$
is continuous.

Comment: Ive seen people use this lamda before but im not sure what it is we havnt worked with it yet in our class. Is it something specific or is it a variable?

Comment: $\lambda$ is just a symbol, if you prefer I use $a$ instead of $\lambda$. In my answer it denotes just a real number.